# Binding doesn't work with inherited attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've a problem to use binding in a ComboBox.

```
   <ComboBox
            Margin="2"
            x:Name="itemSelector"
            SelectionChanged="itemSelector_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

My object is `public class MyButton : MyElement` and the Id attribute is set in MyElement class.

Of course Id is a public attribute: `public string Id;`.
When I try to access a attribute which is in the MyButton class it works but with the "Id" field I got nothing...

Comment: `public string Id;` is a *field*, not a *property* (and both of these are very different from an *attribute*). You cannot databind to fields. `public string Id {get; set;}` is a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to a field; you need to make `Id` a property instead.

Replace your field with `public string Id { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

It should be property (with getter and setter), not field. Because you should notify the UI that the value of the property changed (and you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface)

The code shold look like for C# 5

```
public string Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
}
private string _id;
```

or for C# 4

```
 public string Id
 {
      get { return _id; }
      set
      {
           _id = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Id);
      }
 }
 private DateTime _id;
```

the full code you can see e.g. in this blog post (both for 4 and 5 version of C# language) http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/

(Beware that the C# 5 requres .Net 4.5, therefore your application will not run on WinXP. C# 4 requires .Net4.0 so it has not this limitation.)